# Foreach for quantity and article (fetching data from MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox, foreach

I have a problem showing the quantity for each article I check through a form which is getting data from a MySQL database I made.

Here is my code:

```
        <?php foreach ($results_articles as $input) : ?>
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $input->id_article; ?>_txtbox[]" style="text-align: center; width:30px;"></input>
        <input
            type="checkbox" 
            name="checked_articles[]"
            value="<?php echo $input->id_article; ?>">
        <?php echo "(".
                        ($input->ref_article).")".
                        ($input->nom_article)." (".
                        ($input->prix_article)." €)"; ?><br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So, the "checked_articles" are showing up properly on my next page; but I really don't know how to show the quantity for each article checked.

I would like help from you !

Thanks! If you have any other infos, I'll reply of course!

Comment: What do you mean 'quantity for each article'? Maybe you ment total checked articles count?

Comment: @Hast : No, I mean I can put a number for each articles... It's called the quantity ! ^^'

Answer (score 0):

I presume "quantity" is put in the text `input`, if so it should be accessible using:

```
foreach ($_POST['checked_articles'] as $checked_id)
{
    $quantity = $_POST[$checked_id . '_txtbox'];
}
```

However, since the `txtbox` input is named to become an array, `$quantity` would result in an array. Maybe that is not what you intend. Then you could do it this way instead:

```
<input type="text" name="txtbox[<?php echo $input->id_article; ?>]" style="text-align: center; width:30px;" />
```

Having that, the textbox would be accessible using:

```
$_POST['txtbox'][$checked_id];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
However, it seems like it doesn't show it, because I have to display it in a table:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lb7bP/

Comment: Edit: Sorry, I spoke too fast, I forgot to change the "$checked_id". Now it shows the quantity, but only for the last checked box. How can I do it? Also, I already have this for the "checked_articles": http://jsfiddle.net/fdNE7/1/ (which works perfectly)

Comment: You need to retreive and store the quantity inside the `foreach` loop, just as in your fiddle with `$data_articles[]`, otherwise `$quantity` will be the last checked item.